# Python Pandas pattern serching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good evening,
I have a question about detecting certain pattern. I don't know whether my question has specific terminology.

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
              0       1   ...          8
0           date    price ...     pattern
1     2021-01-01   31.18  ...         0
2     2021-01-02   20.32  ...         1
3     2021-01-03   10.32  ...         1
4     2021-01-04   21.32  ...         -1
5     2021-01-05   44.32  ...         0
6     2021-01-06   45.32  ...         -1
7     2021-01-07   41.32  ...         1
8     2021-01-08   78.32  ...         -1
9     2021-01-09   44.32  ...         1
10    2021-01-10   123.32  ...         1
11    2021-01-11   25.32  ...         -1
```

How can I detect the pattern which is [-1 following after 1] in IF statement.

For example:

Grabbing price column from index 3 and 4 because pattern column at index 3 is 1 and index 4 is -1 which match my condition.
Next would be  index 7 and 8 then index 10 and 11.
I probably convey my question pretty vague, however I don't really know how to describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use three following solutions, but the first and second ones are more pandaic:

First:

```
prices = df.where((df.pattern==-1)&(df.pattern.shift()==1)).dropna().price
```

Second:

```
df['pattern2'] = df.pattern.shift()

# Selecting just prices of meeting condition
prices = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: True if ((x['pattern'] == -1) & (x['pattern2'] == 1)) else False, axis=1), 'price']
```

Third:

```
prices = df.loc[(df.pattern - df.pattern.shift() == -2), 'price']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try shift and check for match

```py
df['pattern_2'] = df['pattern'].shift(1)

df_new = df.iloc[[j for i in df.loc[(df['pattern'] == -1) & (df['pattern_2'] == 1), :].index for j in range(i-1, i+1)], :]

print(df_new)
```

```
         date   price  pattern  pattern_2
2   2021-01-03   10.32        1        1.0
3   2021-01-04   21.32       -1        1.0
6   2021-01-07   41.32        1       -1.0
7   2021-01-08   78.32       -1        1.0
9   2021-01-10  123.32        1        1.0
10  2021-01-11   25.32       -1        1.0
```

Comment: Oh Right, thank you so much. I think I got stuck in IF statement and couldn't get out.. I should think to changing the format. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with boolean indexing.

```
m = df['pattern'].diff(-1).eq(2)
df[m|m.shift()]

          date   price  pattern
3   2021-01-03   10.32        1
4   2021-01-04   21.32       -1
7   2021-01-07   41.32        1
8   2021-01-08   78.32       -1
10  2021-01-10  123.32        1
11  2021-01-11   25.32       -1
```

#### Details

- `df.pattern.diff(-1)` calculates difference b/w *ith* element and *i+1th* element. So, when *ith* element is 1 and *i+1th* is -1 output would be 2(`1 - -1`)
- `_.eq(2)` would marks `True` where the difference is 2.
- `m|m.shift()` is for taken *ith* row as well as *i+1th* row.